# mapping a C struct on memory

Tags: c, makefile

I have to place a structure in a precise position in the memory and I have to find the solution using the linker. (We are talking about C code for embedded systems)

the structure is declared as follows:

**config.c**

```
const conf_t gv_confReg;
```

**config.h**

```
typedef struct
{
    int val1;
    int val2;
} conf_t;

extern const conf_t gv_confReg;
```

I wrote on **Makefile**:

```
...
CFLAGS= -g -DDEBUG=$(DEBUG) -I $(INC) -Xlinker -Map=$(OBJ)/out.map -T linker.ld
...
$(OBJ)/config.o: $(SRC)/config.c $(INC)/conf.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

I wrote on **linker.ld**:

```
MEMORY 
{
    PROM (r) : ORIGIN = 0x40000000, LENGTH = 256k
}

SECTIONS 
{
    . = ORIGIN(PROM);
    .data : {
        *(.data)
        } > PROM : ADDR = 0x40000000
        
        
    .init_array : {
        PROVIDE(__init_array_start = .);
        KEEP(*(.init_array))
        PROVIDE(__init_array_end = .);
    }
}
```

however when I go to examine the addresses, I find that `gv_confReg` is not at the address 0x40000000.
where am I wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to place `.data` in PROM? That doesn't make any sense. Shouldn't your custom section be placed there, rather? As well as `.text` and `.rodata`. And then stack, data and bss at 0x20000000, assuming this is some Cortex M or the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have the struct initialized at that specific address, a memory area must be created specifically for it. E.g. as follows (adjust the size as needed):

```
MEMORY 
{
    CONF (r) : ORIGIN = 0x40000000, LENGTH = 256
    PROM (r) : ORIGIN = 0x40000100, LENGTH = 256k-256
}
...
  .conf :
  {
    KEEP (*(.conf*));
  } >CONF
```

Then tell the compiler to create the struct in that area. The notation is compiler-specific. For GCC:

```
__attribute__((section(".conf"))) const conf_t gv_confReg = {1, 2};
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response, it seems that my structures are mapped to the correct addresses. However, I have a new problem:

I have developed a small code to test your solution where I have written in the linker:
MEMORY
{
rom : ORIGIN = 0x40000000, LENGTH = 128K
ram : ORIGIN = 0x40000000 + 128K , LENGTH = 256K
test_prom : ORIGIN = 0x80000040, LENGTH = 64K
}

The problem is that in my executable (on the .dat file) I also find all the memory between the end of ram and the beginning of test_prom, and it has become very large. How can I prevent this from happening?
Thank you

Comment: @user23554556 It is difficult to say without knowing details of the tool chain. .dat is not an executable format that I know of. You may try if e.g. Intel Hex format can be used instead. In any case, I think that is a separate question.